# Symfony query_builder add null option

Tags: php, symfony

In my Form type I have a select choice which list my team entities.

When I do this
`$builder->add('teams');`
it lists all my teams on my form AND an empty choice, so it's possible to have no team or to remove the team (and that behavior is great for what I have to do).

But when I use a query_builder

```
$builder->add('teams', EntityType::class, array(
                    'class' => Team::class,
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->getTeamsNotRestrictedByAdmin();
                    },
                    'choice_label' => '_name'
                )
            );
```

it returns the entities I want but I don't have that null choice anymore. How could I get it back properly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go with :

```
$builder->add('teams', EntityType::class, array(
                    'class' => Team::class,
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->getTeamsNotRestrictedByAdmin();
                    },
                    'choice_label' => '_name',
                    'required' => false,
                    'empty_data' => ''
                )
        );
```

Comment: Thanks you very much